# Permiso 777 a mis archivos cargados

Tags: php, codeigniter

Necesito poner un **permiso 777** a mis archivos cargados, pero no encuentro ningún documento para subir archivos en codeigniter ...

¿Es posible poner el **permiso 777** con la clase de carga de `codeigniter`?

Ya use

```
if(is_file($config['upload_path'])){
  chmod($config['upload_path'], 777);
}
```

y aún me aparece igual

Comment: ¿Estas utilizando linux?

Comment: No, el servidor a donde va es Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
$ruta = "carpetas/" . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
```